# how to extract this list name

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a response like this:

```
response['results'][0]

(ImageCreative){
   advertiserId = 23
   id = 936
   name = "Banner01-AvailableforiPhoneiPad"
   ..
   }
```

I want to extract this `ImageCreative` which is showing as type in variables but can't get that value using `type(response['results'][0])`

How to get that value?

Edit:

```
[Dbg]>>> type(response['results'][0])
<class 'suds.sudsobject.ImageCreative'>
```

Comment: What does `type(response['results'][0])` print?

Comment: there is no `typeof` as far as I know. You are probably confused with javascript

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Its type()... I am getting some class name. I need that name, can you explain a bit on that?

Comment: HI @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Can you explain a bit on this. I am unable to what this response type is. Is It a dict  or list of dict with metaname?

Comment: it's probably a child class of `dict`

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `__name__` to get the class name.

```
[Dbg]>>> type(response['results'][0]).__name__
'ImageCreative'
```

`__name__`:  From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__)

> `definition.__name__`
>   The name of the class, function, method, descriptor, or generator instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Arpit. But can you explain a bit more this meta value? what it means?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Thanks a lot!